# How to extend ipv4 addresses to 64 bit?

Tags: ipv4

I know that ipv4 addresses are 32 bits. But is it possible to change the ipv4 addresses to 64 bit from 32 bit?

Comment: No. It's a universal standard, not what you uses only on your computer

Comment: @user3258267 What would you put in the remaining 32 bits? And what do you expect others to do with them?

Comment: @Biffen That is what i am asking in my question.

Comment: @user3258267 If so, then that's an odd way of asking that.

Comment: What will you use those stretched IPv4 addresses for? A lot depends on that.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is called enhanced-ipv4 or EnIP, take a look at this document (IPv4 with 64 bit Address Space January 2015):

```
Enhanced IP (EnIP) was designed to minimize impact on core and border routers. ... EnIP packets carry additional address bits and state in an IP option, eliminating routing table updates like IPv6. EnIP supports end-to- end connectivity, a shortcoming of NAT, making it easier to implement mobile networks. Host renumbering is also not required in EnIP as has been the case with other 64-bit protocol proposals
```

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced IP (EnIP) is a method for extending the IP address space from 32-bits to 64-bits.  The 64-bit addresses look like two IP addresses concatenated together.  Enhanced IP is much simpler to implement than IPv6.  To illustrate, there are 432 IPv6 RFCs and 1 Enhanced IP RFC.

```
Examples addresses for comparison:
IPv6 address:   2001:0101:c000:0202:0a01:0102::0
EnIP address:   192.0.2.2.10.1.1.2 
IPv4 address:   192.0.2.2
```

- [Quick intro](http://www.enhancedip.org/learnmore.html) to Enhanced IP
- [Github project](https://github.com/EnIP/enhancedip)